# How can I use Luis to better match city names?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm playing with the *bot framework* and the *cognitive services* from *Microsoft* by doing a chatbot for *Slack*.

- A user asks for the weather in a city, *Luis* recognises the
  `intent`.
- Then a call to a weather API is done with the city that
  *Luis* extracted.

It works pretty well for well-known cities. However, for some others, *Luis* won't match a specific city as a `geographyV2` entity (the prebuilt entity I picked).

Because of that the request to the weather API will be failing since no city has been recognised by *Luis*.

Should I avoid `geographyV2` for another entity or can I help *Luis* in the process?

Here are some classic examples of users inputs:

- How is the weather in Paris?
- What's the weather like in Bangkok
- What is the weather in Olomouc (fails here to recognise Olomouc)
- What's the weather in New York

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few tips based on my experience with that kind of use-cases:

- Prebuilt entities are often good accelerators but if you are in a "non-US" context, you often have problems with things not recognized like you said
- As a consequence, create your own entity and train your LUIS App with a lot of samples and variations in terms of sentences (don't train it only with the same sentence and just another city name)

You will still have missing values sometimes (or sometimes things that are not cities which are found), but it will be better because as you are in a bot:

- if know no entity has been found, you can ask the user "Ok I see that you are looking for the weather, but could you precise where?" and then use directly the result
- if you have a wrong city name, you can see it when you call your weather API and also tell your end-user that you did not understand the city properly

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas for your help. I definitely like that approach. I can't yet upvote your answer but once the 15 reputation points reached on my account I will do so.

Comment: I also gave an upvote on this great answer. Nicolas, I think we've better go for a visit to Olomouc!